# Explain the motivation for grammatical gender for speakers of languages without them

Tags: grammar, gender, history

I am trying to learn German and I learned about grammatical gender. It is interesting but quite confusing to me. What is the purpose if it doesn’t denote sex? Why not use one word in place of many? I don’t mean to complain or argue, I just seek understanding to make sense of this, because it is very destracting to a new learner.

Comment: Related: [Explain the motivation for cases for speakers of languages without them](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/27124/2594)

Comment: They developed [a long time ago](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_nominals#Grammatical_categories), and we kept them.

Comment: Da diejenigen, die die Geschlechter im Germanischen eingeführt haben gestorben sind, ohne ihre Motivation zu hinterlassen, ist die Beantwortung der Frage nicht möglich. Daher ist die Frage eine Meinungssache und gehört geschlossen.

Comment: @userunknown Die Frage nach der eigentlichen Motivation ist nicht zu beantworten (selbst, wenn die ersten Sprecher noch leben würden, schließlich ist die Sprache nicht konstruiert). Den potentiellen Nutzen der Genera aufzuzeigen ist dennoch hilfreich.

Comment: @Chieron: Du siehst den Widerspruch zwischen 'erste Sprecher' und 'nicht konstruiert'? Irgendwann müssen Menschen mit den Geschlechtern begonnen haben, und aus irgendeinem Grunde muss es ihnen hilfreich oder einleuchtend oder praktisch erschienen sein, sonst hätte es sich kaum verbreitet.

Comment: @userunknown Es ist mit der Zeit gewachsen (es gab ja auch keinen ersten Sprecher wie es keinen ersten Menschen gab), vielleicht war es ursprünglich tatsächlich nur Personen vorbehalten, ist dann aber aus Gründen der Nützlichkeit auf alle Wörter erweitert worden. Letztlich ist das egal, denn die Motivation ist nach tausenden Jahren irrelevant, der Gebrauch entscheidet. Möglicherweise sollte man die Frage umformulieren, so dass sie statt nach der unergründlichen Motivation nach dem tatsächlichen Nutzen fragt.

Comment: @Chieron: Bei [http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/genus-gendersprech.php](BellesLettres) gibt es einen Artikel und ein Video (oben, im Artikel, i.d. Box verlinkt) der sich ausführlich mit der Genese des Genus im indogermanischen befasst, viel zu lang, um hier ausgebreitet zu werden, aber Personen war er nicht ursprünglich vorbehalten, sondern im Gegenteil, Sachen, wenn ich mich recht erinnere.

Comment: @userunknown You mis-edited the link -- it's http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/genus-gendersprech.php.

Comment: @userunknown Sehr interessanter und empfehlenswerter Artikel.

Comment: To the current close-voters, jfyi: this question has already survived a close vote and hasn't changed much in the meantime, http://german.stackexchange.com/review/close/13527 - however, one of the original voters changed their mind, so maybe it's some development I've missed.

Answer (score 6):

(My answer doesn't really answers your question, but it is too long for a comment.)

If your native language is English, you may be surprised, because English *had* genders in the past (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_English)). Due to some reasons, genders died out and actually that's not something special (for example, French doesn't have neuter anymore, though it had).

German has genders just because the Proto-Indo-European language (the "parent" of all of Indo-European languages) had them. No doubt, today it's complicated question, why inanimate objects are masculine or feminine, when they should be neuter. But in the past there was no such mess: things, what were considered by people as inanimate were neuter; words indicating people were masculine or feminine. And that was convenient.

But with time, things became confused. Verbs that were regular became irregular, genders get mixed up... And not only in German. For example, in my native language (Russian) there are three genders and animacy (altogether six combinations). A word "robot" can be either animate or inanimate (but always masculine) and that's, I think, funny.

Comment: +1, but can you give a reference for the claim that neutral=inanimate used to hold?

Comment: @Carsten, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_nominals#Grammatical_categories), there is a mention of it. And also references to original research works.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not very comfortable with that question. Languages generally have grown over centuries without asking for "purpose" of specific language features. Language tends to be redundant and not minimalistic, and sometimes the redundancy even serves a purpose - like in literature or poetry - As it does in an everyday conversation.

You could just as well ask why does a language need different words for nearly the same thing - "Do we need both 'boat' and 'ship' if we could say 'small ship' and ''ship'?"

All human conversation has a lot of redundancy - think about it in terms of aural redundancy, not necessarily grammatical redundancy. And in spoken conversation this redundancy serves the purpose of just being easier to understand.

Comment: Was genau ist hier redundant?

Comment: Ich glaube, er spricht über diesen Satz in der Frage: "Why not use one word in place of many?"

Comment: ♪ ♫ "*Ich bin der Wurstfach - Wurstfach - ich bin der Wurstfachverkäufer**in**!*" ♪ - Helge Schneider

Comment: But "boat" is different with "ship". Serves different meaning and easier delivering the message. What do genders do?

Comment: @Eftekhari And "die Band" is different from "das Band" (look it up, please) - So what?

Comment: @torfo Yes. I mean is exactly this. Why not using a different word instead of a different article? For instance instead of "das band" we could say bandana and get the rid of memorizing articles for all the nouns even those that doesn't need haveing them.

Comment: @Eftekhari I'll turn this around. Why not use an article instead of a different word? I doubt the language is going to change just because you propose it...

Comment: @tofro You think differentiating between similar nouns with millions of extra properties in total for all the nouns to memorize could compete with creating new nouns instead?

Comment: There's actually no difference between remembering new words or learning words + articles. Both you need to remember.

Comment: @tofro It it obvious but we are talking about how many new words vs millions of new articles.

Comment: @Eftekhari Erm, no. There are **six** articles in German. Three definite, three indefinite. Not millions. Don't get your comment.

Comment: multiple with number of nouns.

Comment: @tofro Each noun has it's own article specific to it which people should memorize and rarely any could memorize all of them. based on this article >> http://www.k-international.com/blog/why-do-languages-have-gender/

"Don’t be too hard on yourself. One study found that even native French speakers had a hard time agreeing on which gender goes with which word. When asked to assign gender to 93 masculine words, study participants were only able to agree on 17 of them. Even worse, out of a set of 50 feminine words, the group only agreed on one. This stuff is hard. "

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple issues that are solved by having multiple articles.
One of these issues is to decide whether a word, that has the same plural form as the singular, is in plural or not, i.e.

`Das Mädchen - Die Mädchen (the girl - the girls)`

Another problem is homonyms. These are words that are written the same way, but have different meanings. One example would be

`Das Schild - Der Schild (the sign - the shield)`

Sometimes, both of these issues can be resolved with the help of the context, but not always. In these examples I use `the` as universal article.

`Ich sah the Mädchen` One or multiple?

`Sie nahm the Löffel` One spoon or multiple?

`Er hob the Schild` The weapon or his sign he had in the demonstration?

`The Heide ist groß` heath or heathen?

`The See ist gefährlich` lake or sea?

Comment: While your second example is useful (+1 dafür), *die* plural is not a gender. There is no usefulness of the gender-distinction in *Sie nahm den Löfel* vs. *Sie nahm die Löfel*.

Comment: (above, in a non-editable comment, I should have written *Löffel*)

Comment: Das „Schild“-Beispiel sollte andersherum sein. (der Rundschild/das Straßenschild)

Comment: @brian-ammon oh... you are right... don't know what I was thinking xD

Comment: Wieso heißt dann die Parkbank die Bank, und die Deutsche Bank auch die Bank, und nicht eine der beiden 'der Bank' oder 'das Bank'? Oder Bunk? Dass es Unterschiede gibt, die man am Geschlecht des Wortes festmachen kann heißt nicht, dass man den Unterschied nicht anders hätte lösen können, nicht mal, dass das unterschiedliche Geschlecht deswegen zu dem Wort getreten ist. Die Idee ist reine Spekulation und erklärt auch nicht, wieso nicht alle Wörter, bei denen es keine Mehrdeutigkeit gibt, ein Geschlecht haben. Wenn jetzt alle eindeutigen Hauptwörter männlich wären, und nur bei einer ersten ...

Comment: ... Mehrdeutigkeit ein weibliches hinzuträte, und bei einer zweiten dann ein drittes, das wäre ein starkes Indiz. So ist es doch eher eine Phantasie.

Comment: Better choosing new plural form for the cases we face similar single and plural forms. Not using three different types of genders for all the german language.

Comment: @Eftekhari what about synonyms?

Comment: @Armin What is your question?

Comment: @Eftekhari well, how would you differentiate between der Schild (the shield) and das Schild (the sign) without gender?

Comment: @Amir Exactly my question is this. Why not creating a new noun instead of applying three genders to all the nouns? Why did they decide to go in this direction? Logic says with applying three genders to the nouns we make it much much harder for people to use these nouns while we could only create a new noun for synonyms which makes the language less expensive.

Comment: @Eftekhari that's pretty simple, they developed from the same root word.

Comment: @Armin Did you get my question?

Comment: @Eftekhari yes, the answer why they aren't different is because of their development. You can't force development in the language, so you have to keep them, thus synonyms. Furthermore, German isn't the only language with grammatical gender, look at French, swedish, old English, and so on.

Comment: @Armin I'm not asking, Why they don't change now?, I'm asking How they've been created and what's the use of them? Then you said their use is in similar words. Then I said so why they didn't create a new name instead of using 3 gender article? Then you're saying "You can't force development in the language, so you have to keep them, thus synonyms.". What does it mean?

Comment: @Eftekhari I also said that they come from the same root word.

Comment: @Armin Would you please provide an example that shows us using the same noun with a new gender is more beneficial than creating a new noun. Based on the reason of coming from the same root. Thanks.

Comment: @Eftekhari there are no two different nouns, because that is not how languages necessarily develop. It is not what is more beneficial, but what does exist. There are grammatical genders in German, so why shouldn't we use them?

Comment: @Armin I would love to believe you but without an example, I can't. If we have 100,000 nouns and 1000 of them are similar, it is not a big deal to create 1000 new nouns with the similar tone like Band and Bandana in english which are the same word in german.

Comment: @Eftekhari Der Schild and das Schild share the same root (der Schild from middle German scilt). Das Schild was a derivation of der Schild.

Comment: @Armin So? You got my question wrong my friend from the beginning. I asked if anyone could provide an example which indicates using a new noun instead of the same noun with a new gender defects german language. Simpler version >> What will happen if we don't use der Schild and create a new noun like Schildana?

Answer (score 2):

"Gender" is not the best word to denote this grammatical category; think of it as being „noun classes“, which may or may not reflect on real categories of things. Some languages have strict connections between noun classes and reality, such as classes for animate and inanimate, or male, female, neuter, or whatever.
In German, you can and should treat them just as irregular verbs or Perfekt with haben/sein: they're just there. You can explain them scientifically, but for foreign language learners, its 'easier' to just learn them.
Personally, I think that the terms male/female/neuter are crap, as they imply a connection *which just doesn't exist*.

So to answer your question: explain that they are just there for reasons which lie deep in the development of the language, that they have next to no connection to actual biological genders and are called „male/female/neuter“ for stu^H^H^Hhistoric reasons.

About „noun classes“: the most basic definition is, that a language has noun classes if surrounding words such as adjectives have to change according to which word class is used.

Comment: Das Mädchen turnt, der Junge turnt, die Frau turnt. Wo ändern sich Verben mit der Hauptwortklasse? Ich esse, Du isst, er/sie/es isst... Dabei hat es so schön angefangen. Im letzten Abschnitt springe ich ab.

Comment: Nicht im Deutschen, aber in anderen Sprachen, etwa einigen slawischen Sprachen. Ist wohl etwas zu allgemein gehalten. Ich habe mal Adjektive daraus gemacht.

Answer (score 0):

The first and most important answer is: English words have a gender too ("Ho! Ho! and up she rises"); cf. [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She):

> *She* is also used instead of *it* for things to which feminine gender is
>   conventionally attributed: a ship or boat (especially in colloquial
>   and dialect use), often said of a carriage, a cannon or gun, a tool or
>   utensil of any kind, and occasionally of other things.

It's just that the article "the" doesn't reflect it, so you don't have to think that much. (This is, I think, similar to the situation with grammatical case in nouns.)

If you can explain it for English, you are probably very close to an explanation for German.

The answer of course will have to do with language evolution. In a comment to the OP  *user unknown* pointed to an [excellent text](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/genus-gendersprech.php) -- in German, I'm afraid -- detailing the emergence of gender in the indo-germanic language. Originally, contrary to what I thought, there was no gender; gender emerged first as a distinction between subject and subjected, and later to signify certain abstractions (like procedures, or their result). These developments have left certain visible patterns in today's words' gender; for example, the author claims, it's not a coincidence that many abstractions like *Liebe, Kunst, Demokratie* are feminine.

Comment: How would it damage a language if we remove genders (if it has) of nouns? How do genders help a language to deliver ideas in a more convenient way? Why should a language evolve this way that instead of making a new noun for a new object or a new feeling ... in some cases we are using the same noun but with a different article to refer to a different noun?