# Is there a German feminine noun which has the same plural form?

Tags: gender, grammatical-number, curiosity

Is there a German feminine noun whose plural form is itself?

> **Example** (of the noun I am after, but being feminine)
>
> der Löffel / die Löffel

Comment: Words only in plural don't count? Example: [Die Ferien](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ferien)

Comment: Some funny related examples can be found in http://www.deutschplus.net/pages/191 in the 3rd group. There is a female noun with a similar plural noun, but the meaning is changing.

Comment: Yes. I was rather thinking of commenting in a recent [answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/28211/1691), but I refrained to do so, since this information was missing. Second reply, interesting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One candidate is *Mark* (as a currency):

> Dafür bezahlte man fünf Mark.

However, it could be argued that this is not really plural, but a unit-of-measure singular (cf. *zehn Grad*, *zwanzig Stück*).

Another candidate is the acronym *SMS*, which in Germany (not in Austria or Switzerland) is feminine:

> Ich habe zwei SMS von ihm bekommen.

There are two regular feminine words that form a plural without ending, but the plural form has umlaut: *Mutter* – *Mütter*, *Tochter* – *Töchter*.

Normally, null plural is limited to masculine and neutral nouns.

Comment: Das SMS ist aber (zumindest in Österreich) sächlich. Außerdem habe ich auch schon mehrfach den Plural SMSen gehört (gesprochen: eine ess-em-ess und noch eine ess-em-ess sind zwei ess-em-essen.) Laut Wiktionary lauter der Plural von Mark übrigens nur in dem von dir richtig angeführten Fall der Währungseinheit ebenfalls Mark. Die Awarenmark und die Steiermark sind aber nicht zwei Mark, sondern zwei Marken.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast In Deutschland wird SMS meistens feminin gebraucht. Der Duden führt beide Varianten: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/SMS_per_SMS_verschickte_Nachricht, merkt aber an, das die sächliche Form eher in AT und CH gebräuchlich ist.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Ah, interessant – das wußte ich nicht, daß sich das Genus hier in den verschiedenen Varietäten unterscheidet (interessanterweise mit der gleichen Verteilung wie bei _Mail_). In Deutschland ist, wie Polygnome schon sagte, _SMS_ normalerweise ein Femininum, und auch der Plural ist normalerweise identisch mit dem Singular.

Comment: @chirlu: Österreichisches Standard-Deutsch: Das SMS, das E-Mail, das Cola, das Service (sowohl Dienstleistung als auch Kaffeegeschirr; mit unterschiedlicher Aussprache, aber beide sächlich), das Puff (Bordell), das Keks. Aber: Die Ausschank (Theke), die Schneid, der Spray, der Gummi. In den meisten Fällen wird in Österreich auch die deutsche Variante akzeptiert, und teilweise sogar auch aktiv verwendet. Aber bei »*die* Cola«, »*das* Spray« und »*das* Gummi« rollen sich beim eingeborenen Ösi die Zehennägel auf. Das fällt eindeutig in die Kategorie »Sprachekel«. (nicht böse gemeint)

Comment: Interessanterweise gibt es da einen Unterschied zwischen Mark und Pfennig: Während die Mark nur als Maßeinheit verwendet wird, kann der Pfennig auch das Geldstück bezeichnen, und hat dann auch einen Plural: "Da liegen fünf Pfennige." Aus irgendeinem Grund ist das aber bei der Mark nicht der Fall, und es heißt stattdessen "Da liegen fünf Markstücke". "Pfennigstücke" habe ich hingegen noch nie gehört, auch nicht, als man hierzulande noch mit Mark und Pfennig gezahlt hat.

Comment: @celtschk: In einigen umgangsprachlichen Varianten konnte man früher "gib mir fünf Märker" hören.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers ATOW miss the point that for a "word" to have the same "wordforms" they must be the same in singular and plural in the corresponding declination case, not only for the nominative case, i.e. sing.nom. = pl.nom., sing.akk. = pl.akk., sing.dat. = pl.dat., and sing.gen. = pl.gen.

AFIK all pl.dat. forms end with an "n" wich is always different form the sing.dat form.

In your example LÖFFEL you have *der Löffel* [sing.dat.] vs. *den Löffeln* [pl.dat.]

Comment: Not true for the candidates discussed in [my answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/28228): _Mit fünf Mark sind Sie dabei!_ _Nach dem Erfolg ertrank ihr Handy geradezu in SMS mit Glückwünschen._

Comment: As a unit of measurement *Mark* is used like a singularetantum and strictly seen it would lack of a plural form. The *SMS* example ist indeed more interesting. But AFIK most of the native speakers would tend to use the form *SMSen*, specially in ambiguous contextes.

Answer (score -2):

I have one that is a bit of cheat, which is "die Milch", which in colloquial use can become countable, so that you can order "zwei Milch" in a restaurant or similar. But technically, similar to the Mark above, that is more like a unit of measure than a real plural.

Comment: *Milch* ist ein Stoffname und daher ein Singularetantum, also ein Wort, das es eigentlich nur im Singular, nicht aber im Plural gibt. (Wie auch Erde, Sand, Wasser, Honig, ...). Allerdings gibt es doch eine Verwendung dieser Worte im Plural, nämlich wenn verschiedene Arten gemeint sind. Erden sind Erdarten, Sande sind Sandarten, Honige Honigarten usw. Das geht auch bei der Milch. Allerdings ist »Milch« nicht der Plural von »Milch«. Milch hat zwei Plural-Versionen, die beide fachsprachlich verwendet werden wenn von Milcharten die Rede ist: Milche und Milchen. https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Milch

Comment: In deinem Beispiel »Herrr Ober, bitte zwei Milch« ist »zwei Milch« eine Verkürzung von »zwei Glas Milch«. Dabei ist nicht »Milch« die Maßeinheit, sondern »Glas«. Milch ist das gemessene Gut, und weil Milch als Stoffname keinen Plural hat, steht es hier im Singular. Wenn du da einen Plural haben willst, dann kannst du die Einheit im Plural verwenden: »zwei Gläser Milch«. Aber auch hier bleibt die nichtzählbare Milch in der Einzahl.